# how to get value if keys are matching with array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I have written one array as below

```
const OBJECT = {
    '3': 'History And Social Sciences',
    '5': 'Humanities',
    '8': 'Global Studies And Social Impact',
    '10': 'Sanskrit'
};

var rou=[3,5,8,10];
```

I want to fetch the field values when keys are matching with values. Does anyone have any idea on it?

Answer (score 2):

`map` over `rou` and get the value from `OBJECT` of that key:

```js
const OBJECT = {
  '3': 'History And Social Sciences',
  '5': 'Humanities',
  '8': 'Global Studies And Social Impact',
  '10': 'Sanskrit',

};

var rou = [3, 5, 8, 10];
var values = rou.map(k => OBJECT[k]);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: There is a problem if array contains a value that is not present inside the object it will console undefined.

Answer (score 0):

rou[0] is 3 , rou[1] is 5 and so on. What you want is to check if rou[0] that has the value 3, is key to you dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value from the object like this

```
var value = OBJECT.rou[0]
```

Iterate 'rou' array and for each value of it find the corresponding value in the OBJECT

Answer (score 0):

```
   Iterator<String> it = jsonObject.keys(); 
   List<Integer> list=new ArrayList();
   while(it.hasNext()){
   int key = it.next(); 
   list.add(key);
   }
```

Comment: The question is asked for Javascript and not Java

Comment: Please provide some explanation - what makes you think that this code solves the given problem?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the object properties and compare if the key is found in arr by **indexOf** if found get the value of that key.

```js
const OBJECT = {'3': 'History And Social Sciences','5': 'Humanities','8': 'Global Studies And Social Impact','10': 'Sanskrit','a': 'abc'};

var rou = [3, 5, 8, 10];

for (var property in OBJECT) {
  if (OBJECT.hasOwnProperty(property) && rou.indexOf(parseInt(property)) != -1) {

    console.log(OBJECT[property]);
  }
}
```

You can also do it by iterating the array and if the element of array is present in the object get the value of that object

```js
    const OBJECT = {'3': 'History And Social Sciences','5': 'Humanities','8': 'Global Studies And Social Impact','10': 'Sanskrit','a': 'abc'};

    var rou = [3, 5, 8, 10];

    rou.forEach(function(element) {
      if (OBJECT[element] != undefined) {
        console.log(OBJECT[element]);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With [ramdajs' pick](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick), it's easier.

```
R.pick(['a', 'd'], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //=> {a: 1, d: 4}
R.pick(['a', 'e', 'f'], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //=> {a: 1}
```

If you're interested, check its [implementation](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.26.1/source/pick.js)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const OBJECT = {
    '3': 'History And Social Sciences',
    '5': 'Humanities',
    '8': 'Global Studies And Social Impact',
    '10': 'Sanskrit'
};

var rou=[3,5,8,10];

var res = Object.keys(OBJECT).reduce((acc, cur) => rou.indexOf(parseInt(cur)) !== -1 ? (acc.push(OBJECT[cur]), acc) : acc, [])

console.log(res)
```